# Systemd script not running python script with config.ini

Tags: python-3.x, linux, cron, raspberry-pi, systemd

I have an error when creating a systemd service I don't understand.

I run a python script for air quality on an rpi. I runs it using the following code:

```
python3 senddata.py "./config.ini"
```

This run correctly; however, I want to make it a systemd service to later setup a cron job. I drafted this up:

```
[Unit]
Description=aqi
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/.../senddata.py "./config.ini"

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When I run it I reload the daemon and restart the service, but get the following error:

```
python3[...]: KeyError parsing config.ini file.
```

Is it not understanding my quotes for the config.ini when attempting to run?

Thanks!

Resources:
https://ayeks.de/post/2018-05-29-bme680-influxdb-grafana/
https://github.com/ayeks/bme680_to_influxdb/blob/master/grafana_dashboard.json

Comment: Put the full path to the config.ini file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of curiosity - I made a custom service with just 'ls' - to see what directory was the current one when starting a service with systemctl.

The output in the system journal leads me to believe it's starting with "/" as the current directory. I executed 'systemctl start test' from /etc/systemd/system - not in "/"..

```
[Unit]
Description=aqi
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/ls

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target



Oct 30 13:11:40 oelinux2 ls[1951]: bin
Oct 30 13:11:40 oelinux2 ls[1951]: boot
Oct 30 13:11:40 oelinux2 ls[1951]: dev
Oct 30 13:11:40 oelinux2 ls[1951]: etc
Oct 30 13:11:40 oelinux2 ls[1951]: home
Oct 30 13:11:40 oelinux2 ls[1951]: lib
Oct 30 13:11:40 oelinux2 ls[1951]: lib64
Oct 30 13:11:40 oelinux2 ls[1951]: media
Oct 30 13:11:40 oelinux2 ls[1951]: mnt
Oct 30 13:11:40 oelinux2 ls[1951]: opt
Oct 30 13:11:40 oelinux2 ls[1951]: proc
Oct 30 13:11:40 oelinux2 ls[1951]: root
Oct 30 13:11:40 oelinux2 ls[1951]: run
Oct 30 13:11:40 oelinux2 ls[1951]: sbin
Oct 30 13:11:40 oelinux2 ls[1951]: srv
Oct 30 13:11:40 oelinux2 ls[1951]: sys
Oct 30 13:11:40 oelinux2 ls[1951]: tmp
Oct 30 13:11:40 oelinux2 ls[1951]: usr
Oct 30 13:11:40 oelinux2 ls[1951]: var
```

ls command on same machine from /

```
[root@oelinux2 /]# ls
bin  boot  dev  etc  home  lib  lib64  media  mnt  opt  proc  root  run  sbin  srv  sys  tmp  usr  var
[root@oelinux2 /]#
```

My first thought.. is to change "./config" to the full path of where 'config' is located. Try that and see if it can find it.